# Битрикс региональные папки

Tags: битрикс, cms

Просили сделать регионы по типу site.com/spb/..., при этом в разделы каталога необходимо создавать свои, а товары брать из существующего (привязкой к элементу, указанием id товара и тд.).

Вопрос, возможно ли такое средствами самого Битрикс.

Я сделал модуль и столкнулся с проблемами, например:

1. регионы не реализованы как раздел, т.е. пути (URI) разделов необходимо менять
   при использовании GetList (SetUrlTemplates).
2. получить товары через GetList не получится,
   т.е. измененный компонент это понимает,
   а если кто-то в шаблоне использует GetList
   то это не сработает.

В общем появляются проблемы с дополнительным функционалом
в самих шаблонах, а если все это под простыней других подулей,
то просто SetUrlTemplates без копии такого подуля с незначительными
изменениями не получится, если сам модуль не предоставляет API
для этого.

Поэтому возник вопрос, может это все не нужно и на самом деле
Битрикс в состоянии решить эту проблему.

Comment: Регионы можно включить как корневые разделы, но тогда поля регионов и разделов будут вперемешку что тоже не очень, конечно можно настроить желаемый вывод для контент-менеджера, 
но тем не менее для программиста (меня) все будет выглядеть вперемешку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас (допустим) есть товар1 и товар2... Надо сделать каталоги site.ru/spb/sec1/tovar1 и site.ru/msk/secDrugoeImya/tovar1 ? - т.е. пусти разные, но по сути детальная страничка товара одна.

*Как на подумать: У такого сайта будут проблемы с СЕО или же придется хорошо поправить код и делать различные автоматические правки СЕОшной информации для одинаковых страниц но по разным ссылкам.*

**Возможные решения задачи**:
Можно в каталоге создать нужную структуру разделов, а товар разместить в эти несколько разных разделов (не помню с какой версии, но в Битрикс это давно возможно).

Другой вариант. Нельзя в каталоге разделы первого уровня сделать как spb, msk и т.д. Можно физически сделать разделы на хостинге/сервере и в каждый раздел положить компонент, но тогда компонент будет повторять структуру разделов инфоблока.

Еще как вариант, создать `Тип инфоблока` - Каталог, а в нем кучу `инфоблоков` с кодами - инфоблок spb, инфоблок msk, инфоблок ivanovo и т.д. - в каждом инфоблоке может быть своя структура разделов, а товар привязывается через дополнительное свойство из другого инфоблока (общего). В настройках `компонента каталога` для пути использовать код инфоблока, код раздела, код элемента.

Ну и всегда можно написать свой комплексный компонент, который будет использовать свою логику (с формированием тех же нужных правильных чпу ссылок), а для вывода списка разделов и товаров использовать битриксо-компоненты внутри своего комплексного компонента.

Comment: Вариант с несколькими инфоблоками меня заинтересовал. Вообще насколько помню просили перечислять ID элементов через запятую, но в общем решение с регионами-инфоблоками интересное, учитывая что ссылки по GetList будут правильные, что исправит косяк с GetList в шаблонах (не надо будет править этот код). Другое дело насколько это прожорливо будет по памяти. СЕО и решается этим модулем: подмена названий, мета тегов и др.

Comment: Я по сути переписал bitrix:catalog на свой лад с его простыми копонентами, однако на нестандартном функционале не все заработало, но с огромной вероятностью заработает с вариантом со своими инфоблоками для разделов регионов, а для перечисления ID через запятую или другого интерфейса можно создать административные страницы модуля, звучит неплохо как минимум.

Comment: Полагаю это ответ.

Comment: А сейчас подумал что и менять особо ничего не надо, просто добавить немного функционала в текущий вариант, в общем отличное решение.

Comment: Рад был помочь.